# Creating Delay in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am relatively new to js and want to make a simple thing that changes an image when you click on it and then a couple of seconds later it reverts it to the first image again. It works to click on it, but then it never changes back. Here's my JavaScript:

```
function animation(){
  var boom = document.getElementById("boom");
    document.getElementById("boom").src = "file:///C:/Users/domin/Desktop/Atom/rootfolder/Boom%20Salamon/Salamon.png";
}

if (boom.style.src == "file:///C:/Users/domin/Desktop/Atom/rootfolder/Boom%20Salamon/Salamon.png") {
  setTimeout(() => { document.getElementById("boom").src =
  "file:///C:/Users/domin/Desktop/Atom/rootfolder/Boom%20Salamon/Boom!.png";("World!"); }, 2000);
}
```

What's happening. I'm confused.

Comment: @Arne `var` is global. If the `animation` function is run before the if statement, then it is available

Comment: Are the errors in the browser console?

Comment: Your if statement is run only on page load. You need to move your if statement to the end of your animation function (you can discard the if statement and use just the timeout part since that condition will always be true).  edit: oh and also you are declaring boom variable in your function but using it outside of it. It is out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

Just put them together in `animation` function. Now it's not completely clear what is the order of execution of those pieces of code.

```js
const boom = document.getElementById("boom");
const origSrc = boom.src;

function animation(){
    boom.src = "https://wholesalecelticvapours.com/media/catalog/product/s/a/sample-icon.png";
    setTimeout(() => { boom.src = origSrc }, 2000);
}

boom.addEventListener('click', animation);
```

```html
<img id="boom" src="https://previews.123rf.com/images/aquir/aquir1311/aquir131100316/23569861-sample-grunge-red-round-stamp.jpg" width="150" height="150" />
<div>
click the image
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrote in the condition:

```
boom.style.src == "..."
```

`‍‍src‍‍‍` ‍The image is not in `style`

**Example:**

```js
function animation(){
  var boom = document.getElementById("boom");
    document.getElementById("boom").src = "https://via.placeholder.com/420.png?text=Image+One";
}

if (boom.src == "https://via.placeholder.com/420.png?text=Image+One") {
  setTimeout(() => { document.getElementById("boom").src =
  "https://via.placeholder.com/420.png?text=Image+Two";("World!"); }, 2000);
}
```

```html
<img id='boom' src="https://via.placeholder.com/420.png?text=Image+One">
```

**My code:**

```js
var boom = document.getElementById("boom");
let imageOne = "https://via.placeholder.com/420.png?text=Image+One+Click+Me";
let imageTwo = "https://via.placeholder.com/420.png?text=Image+Two";

boom.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (boom.src == imageOne) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      boom.src = imageTwo;
      setTimeout(() => {
        boom.src = imageOne;
      }, 2000);
    }, 2000);
  }
});
```

```html
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/420.png?text=Image+One+Click+Me" id='boom'>
```